# run UI automation against iOS app using Appium, on windows platform using VS2015?

Tags: ios, appium

is there any way to run UI automation against iOS app using Appium, on windows platform using VS2015 ? Can we use Xamarian for this

Comment: yes, you can use C# code for appium.

Comment: can u please elaborate a little further that how it can be done.

Comment: you can use **TestProject framework** to enhances Appium driver and now enables you to run Appium tests on Windows operating system without the need for macOS. you can use this [link](https://blog.testproject.io/2018/06/11/ios-test-windows-without-mac/) as reference